# Deadlock because of fulltext index - FTS_DOC_ID_INDEX in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, deadlock

We are having an issue with one of our innodb tables. This table has primary key on integer column (and this one is not auto increment column ) and fulltext key on one of the text columns, Application is executing multiple insert queries and these inserts are not overlapping with Primary key but still we are getting deadlocks show engine innodb status is suggesting FTS_DOC_ID_INDEX reason for Deadlock. How to fix or avoid this issue apart from retrying when deadlock occurs?

MySQL Version : 5.7.24 Table type : innodb

Also there is no Unique key in the table.

Below is the output of deadlock section of show engine innodb status : (Replaced Server/database/table details to avoid exposure of critical information )

```
=====================================
2022-08-22 10:22:35 0x7fae05ad3700 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
=====================================
Per second averages calculated from the last 58 seconds
-----------------
BACKGROUND THREAD
-----------------
srv_master_thread loops: 5100434 srv_active, 0 srv_shutdown, 1221867 srv_idle
srv_master_thread log flush and writes: 6322131
----------
SEMAPHORES
----------
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 1016456164
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: signal count 1057082672
RW-shared spins 0, rounds 1491795151, OS waits 511567804
RW-excl spins 0, rounds 23862155598, OS waits 433940699
RW-sx spins 61962073, rounds 1270936989, OS waits 18274894
Spin rounds per wait: 1491795151.00 RW-shared, 23862155598.00 RW-excl, 20.51 RW-sx
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2022-08-21 11:26:55 0x7fae05041700
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 1242662421, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 3 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 2 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 704979717, OS thread handle 140384861812480, query id 55616782199 XXX.XX.XX.XXX XX_XX update
replace into  TABLE_NAME (COLUMN_NAMES)
VALUES(XX)
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 50573 page no 864080 n bits 576 index FTS_DOC_ID_INDEX of table `DB_NAME`.`TABLE_NAME` trx id 1242662421 lock_mode X insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 1242662416, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting, thread declared inside InnoDB 5000
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
5 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 16 row lock(s), undo log entries 14
MySQL thread id 704979700, OS thread handle 140385385191168, query id 55616782204 XXX.XX.XX.XXX XX_XX update
replace into  TABLE_NAME (COLUMN_NAMES)
VALUES(XX)
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 50573 page no 864080 n bits 560 index FTS_DOC_ID_INDEX of table `DB_NAME`.`TABLE_NAME` trx id 1242662416 lock_mode X
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 50573 page no 864080 n bits 576 index FTS_DOC_ID_INDEX of table `DB_NAME`.`TABLE_NAME` trx id 1242662416 lock_mode X insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)
```

Comment: The `PRIMARY KEY` is a UNIUQE key.

Comment: @RickJames  Yes I meant there is no other unique key in the table apart from Primary key.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`  (I'm leaning toward recommending a bug report at bugs.mysql.com)

Comment: @RickJames Output added in question for SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS.

Comment: Are you doing `replace into  TABLE_NAME (COLUMN_NAMES) VALUES(XX)`?  Or is FULLTEXT doing that?  How many UNIQUE KEYs on the table?  Are they among the "COLUMN_NAMES"?  If you are performing the REPLACE, is it practical to change to IODKU (upsert)?

Comment: @RickJames Yes we are doing replace into , There are no unique keys in the table only primary key is there that too on single integer column  , As far as I understood FTS_DOC_ID_INDEX is generated by MySQL internally. upsert require changes on many levels however we can try but need to find out why this behaviour  in case of replace into !

Comment: Add code to rerun the `REPLACE` if it fails.

Comment: @RickJames yes error handling we can do , but root cause and how to avoid this is what we are looking for primarily , It will be interesting to know why fulltext index is causing deadlock .

Comment: Yes, it would be better to find (and fix) the root cause.  I (and apparently no one else) don't know the root cause.  So, the best I can do is to provide a workaround.